# Unity resolve using type from derived class

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to setup a structure where I have two sets of derived classes (models and views) implementing a common interface, and I want to use Unity to allow me to create/resolve a view from a model instance. E.g.,

```
public interface ICommonA {}

public class ModelA : ICommonA {}
public class ViewA : ICommonA {}

public static void Main() {
    // Setup Unity container - register ICommonA to resolve ViewA objects
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<ICommonA, ViewA>();

    // At some point, we begin with a ModelA object.
    ModelA m = new ModelA();

    // Then, I want to automate the creation of ViewX objects from ModelX objects 
    // (I will have many such pairs) without checking exactly which type of model 
    // I currently have.
    var v = container.Resolve(m.GetType(), String.Empty);

    // Do something with v now.
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't simply ask Unity to resolve from the model type (ModelA), it doesn't seem to automatically scan the type's interfaces and find one that was registered. I know I can resolve the view by explicitly checking each incoming model type and resolving for exactly the interface I need using `container.Resolve<ICommonA>(String.Emtpy)`, but I was hoping to have a more generic resolve step which allows me to add more model/view types without needing to update my resolution code to check for new model types.

Is this possible in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your "model" needs to provide information on what type of view to use. Couple possible options are specify type directly or specify name for named registration of known interface:

With type (assuming `model.GetViewType()` return `typeof(ViewA)`)

```
 var view = container.Resolve(model.GetViewType(), String.Empty);
```

With named registration (assuming `model.GetViewRegistrationName()` returns "SomeName")

```
 container.RegisterType<ICommonA, ViewA>("SomeName");
 var view = container.Resolve(typeof(ICommonA), 
   model.GetViewRegistrationName());
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your idea of storing the associated view type. I will implement it using a Dictionary that I setup to map model types to the associated view types, but essentially your first idea.